# What's the difference between skimage morphology's h_maxima and peak_local_max?

Tags: python, computer-vision, scikit-image

I am trying to understand the difference between the `h_maxima` and `peak_local_max` methods.
They both search for the same thing but use different approaches, right? If so, what criterion should be used to determine which one to choose?

Answer (score 1):

The two methods find local maxima, but use different strategies to filter them:

- `h_maxima` selects local maxima that have a minimal height above the baseline, which is defined by the lowest point you pass when going from one local maxima to a neighboring one.
- `peak_local_max` selects local maxima by a minimal distance to neighboring local maxima. A local maximum is discarded if there’s a taller one close by.

More often than not, the `h_maxima` method is the most meaningful one. But `peak_local_max` can be quite useful for finding peaks in a Hough parameter space, for example, where nearby maxima represent similar lines, you’d only want to select the stronger one of those similar lines.